# How do I return a row for every day in a date range, even if there are no records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have data like this:

```
| DateAndTime         | Amount |
|---------------------|--------|
| 2018-03-01 10:00:00 | 1      |
| 2018-03-01 10:15:00 | 1      |
| 2018-03-03 08:30:00 | 1      |
```

As you can see... 2018-03-02 has no records...

But in my results I want to aggregate for a chart like this:

```
| Date       | Total |
|------------|-------|
| 2018-03-01 | 2     |
| 2018-03-02 | 0     |
| 2018-03-03 | 1     |
```

How would I include the days for which there is no source data?

Thanks!

Comment: outer join a calendar table (having all possible dates.)

Comment: The real answer is to make the frontend fill in the gaps. Presentation isn't SQL's job. However, iirc, SSRS for example can't do this, so MS aren't making it easy to do the right thing...

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5078f8f53be7cbf40ed13184e2ac9b9 Check my Solution may help you

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursive `cte` approach

```
;with cte as (
    select min(cast(dates as date)) mindate, max(cast(dates as date)) maxdate
    from table t
    union all
    select DATEADD(day, 1, mindate) mindate, maxdate 
    from cte c
    where c.mindate < c.maxdate
)

select c.mindate as date, count(t.amt) Total  
from cte c left join table t 
           on t.dates = c.mindate 
group by c.mindate
```